# System Commands - Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a little java program that executes a system command but I can't seem to figure it out

The question is how does one execute a system command using java?

UPDATE: I read the documentation & tried some examples & I still can't figure it out. Why can't it be simple like in C.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call System commands from a java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693740/how-to-call-system-commands-from-a-java-program)

Comment: As I said in my answer, for simple cases it is indeed dirt simple. If you're trying to do something more complicated, perhaps you need to explain what that more complicated use case actually is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to have a look into the documentation for [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). An example is given there.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, you use the family of `exec()` methods in the `java.lang.Runtime` class. There's a class named `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` which helps in setting up a process to run, although you're not obligated to use it. Be sure to read [this classic article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) on handling the input and output streams, running Windows CMD.EXE builtins, and other potential pitfalls.

Running a command can be as simple as saying

```
Runtime.exec("notepad");
```

but as that article points out, there are plenty of subtleties to worry about.

Comment: I made a little test: Runtime.exec("ls") and when I compile it gives an error about non-static methods that cannot be referenced from static cont ext

Comment: @Samantha Catania Please try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);`.

Answer (score 2):

[Process Builder example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html)

Answer (score 1):

Apache [Commons-Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html) is similar to `ProcessBuilder`, but helps avoid a lot of common problems with the streams, process timeout, platform differences, etcetera. I recommend using that instead of `ProcessBuilder`.